# How to force evaluation of value in Debug.log

Tags: elm

Using Elm 0.17, I'd sometimes like to see the steps taken during a computation, such as:

```
let
    names = Debug.log "accounts"
        List.map (\x -> x.name) accounts

    sortedNames = Debug.log "sorted accounts"
        List.sortBy String.toLower names

    options =
        List.map (viewAccountOption selectedName) sortedNames
in
    [ viewEmptyOption ] ++ options
```

This logs the following:

```
accounts: <function>
sorted accounts: <function:sortBy>
```

I understand Elm is lazy, and the thunks will be evaluated when the values are actually needed.

I couldn't find a `force` or `strict` function in [elm-core Basics](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/4.0.1/Basics), or anywhere else in the package.

Is there a way to force evaluation of a value?

Comment: Just as a comment... Elm is not lazy, that is, all instructions are executed immediately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by either using parenthesis:

```
Debug.log "accounts"
    (List.map (\x -> x.name) accounts)
```

Or using the `<|` operator

```
Debug.log "accounts" <|
    List.map (\x -> x.name) accounts
```

EDIT:

The reason is that Debug.log was evaluated with `List.map` (a function) as the second argument and then returned that argument to be composed with the rest of the line. You just needed to hint elm a bit on what was your intended argument precedence